# User's Liked page on Facebook

Tags: facebook

How can I get all the pages liked by a user in one request? currently, by graph API It is possible to get up to 50 likes in one call but then, If there are 1000 likes then the performance will ve very slow.

Is it possible without FQL?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is either possible via the Graph API using paging, or via FQL specifying the LIMIT parameter. If you have a Graph API <=v2.0 app, I'd recommend to stick with FQL.